# QextSerialPort - detect disconnection

Tags: c++, c, qextserialport

I have a device connected to the computer as "COM8". I'd like to know when it is unplugged from the computer, so I used the following code to detect:

```
m_receiverCom->isWritable();
m_receiverCom->isOpen();
```

However, they still returned true **after I unplugged the device**. How can I detect whether the device is plugged or not ?

Comment: Have you considered using QtSerialPort? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You queried the port, not the device. Send some kind of query message to the device that will produce a response message.

Answer (score 0):

Although an old thread, prevent people from getting stuck. I just ran into this problem, and I successfully used qextserialport to detect serial port disconnect/connect using:

```
QextSerialPort *serial_monitor;
serial_monitor = new QextSerialEnumerator();
serial_monitor->setUpNotifications();

connect(serial_monitor, SIGNAL(deviceRemoved(QextPortInfo)), this, SLOT(_handleUSBError(QextPortInfo)));
```